# how to place marker on angular google map by auto complete?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to place marker on google-angular-map by auto complete search, I am getting location in form of latitude and longitude but marker is not adding, Please check it....

**Controller code is**

```
$timeout(function() {

          var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
          var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);

          google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
             var marker= [] ;
             var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

             if (places.length == 0) {
               return;
             }

            var loc_data = {            

              coords: {
                  latitude: places[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                  longitude: places[0].geometry.location.lng()
              }
            };
            marker.push(loc_data);
            $scope.markers=marker;              
          });
```

HTMl code is

```
    <ui-gmap-markers models="markers" idkey="markers.id" coords="'coords'" >

    </ui-gmap-markers>

<div class="col-md-4">

    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
</div>
```

Comment: You are missing `id` variable in `var loc_data`.

Comment: @IvanJovovic yes, you are right, now I am able to add marker but It only show when I open console, means My Map is not automatically updating.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="pacinput" class="control-label col-md-4">Search Location</label>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <input id="pacinput" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search Location">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8">
                                    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="address" />
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="txtLat" runat="server" />
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="txtLng" runat="server" />
                                    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 380px;">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

// This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
        // feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
        // pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

```
    // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
    // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
    // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

    function initAutocomplete() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: { lat: 15.362813, lng: 75.126129 },
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pacinput');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function () {
            searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        var markers = [];
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function () {
            var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

            if (places.length == 0) {
                return;
            }

            // Clear out the old markers.
            markers.forEach(function (marker) {
                marker.setMap(null);
            });
            markers = [];

            // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            places.forEach(function (place) {
                var icon = {
                    url: place.icon,
                    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                };

                // Create a marker for each place.
                markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    icon: icon,
                    title: place.name,
                    position: place.geometry.location
                }));

                if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                    // Only geocodes have viewport.
                    bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
                } else {
                    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
                }
            });
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a marker to place it on your map.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: loc_data.coords,
          map: yourMapID
        });
```

And if you want to add a drop animation or listeners:

```
   marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);
   marker.addListener('click', yourHandlerFunction);
```